$ABCD$ is a square and $\angle GDF=45^{\circ}$ and $DH \perp FG$. Prove that $DH=AD$.
The problem:

$ABCD$ is a square and $\angle GDF=45^{\circ}$ and $DH \perp FG$.
Prove that $DH=AD$.



What I have tried:
I tried some reverse-engineering: If $DH=AD$ we have $\triangle DHG\cong DAG$. So we should prove that $\angle GDH=\angle GDA$. Here I drew the diagonal $BD$ for the square:

As $\angle GDF=\angle ADB = 45^{\circ}$, we have $\angle BDF = \angle GDA$ (marked as green and red in the image).
Hence, we need to prove $\angle BDF = \angle HDG$. In other words, we should prove $\angle BDG = \angle HDF$ (because of $\angle GDH = \angle GDA$, as mentioned earlier).
I'm not sure how to continue from here.

You made a great observation at the start, but aren't quite able to capitalize on it. $BD$ doesn't seem that relevant, and complicates things further.

Call $\angle{CDF}=\alpha$. What happens when you reflect $CD$ over $CF$? What angle remains?

@RobinSparrow Ok, so it is enough to show that the reflection of $C$ will lie on $GF$.

@RobinSparrow Now it is interesting, calling $\angle CDF=\alpha$, we have $\angle GDA=45-\alpha$ and when we fold along $DF$ and $DG$ sum of these angles will be $45^{\circ}$ and as there are right angles in the square, $CF$ and $AG$ will be on a line. It actually reminded me of Origami!

@user1380196 That last observation can lead to a solution. How can we push through?

@CalvinLin I understood intuitively that $DH$ is equal to the side of the square. Do you mean how to state it formally?

Rotate $F$ clockwise about $D$ by $90^\circ$ to $F'$, which is to copy $\triangle DCF$ as $\triangle DAF'$. Then $\triangle GDF \cong \triangle GDF'$ (SAS), so their altitudes from $D$ have the same length.

Similar to @Prem solution 1, but I would not use circles to solve this question.



Extend $BA$ to point $E$ so that $AE=CF$. We can prove that $\triangle AED$ is congruent to $\triangle CFD$ as $SAS.$
As $ED=FD$, $\triangle DEG$ and $\triangle DFG$ have the common line GD, and $\angle EDG=\angle GDF=45^o$. We can prove that $\triangle DEG$ is congruent to $\triangle DFG$ as $SAS$.
As $\triangle DEG$ is congruent to $\triangle DFG$, we can say that these two triangles have the same area.
As $\frac{1}{2} AD\times EG=\frac{1}{2}DH \times GF$, and $EG=GF$, we can conclude that $AD=DH$.

Image without MSE artifacts ( Eg vertical lines & voting controls ) would be less distracting.

INTUITION :
Assuming what is given is indeed true , let us see what we get.
Imagine the Circle with Center $D$ , going though $A$ , $C$ , $H$ :

We will have tangents at $A$ , $C$ , $H$ ,  which intersect at $F$ , $G$
Then the Tangents will give $CF=FH$ , $HG=GA$
More-over , we have $\triangle DCF \cong DHF$ , $\triangle DAG \cong DHG$
Then the angles at $D$ are shared by the Congruent triangles , hence the necessary angle is $90/2=45$
SOLUTION 1 :
With that Intuition , we can "reverse-engineer" the Solution.
We have to show that we have the Congruent triangles where the two angles at $D$ are $x$ , $45-x$.
Here we can see that every Point $G$ ( which is moving along $AB$ ) can generate a tangent to the Circle at $H$ , while giving the Point $F$
In all those ways , we have $DH=DA$
There is never a way to not have $DH=DA$
SOLUTION 2 :
We can use trigonometry.
Let the Square have $Side=1$
In the right-angle triangle with $y$ , we have $\sin (y) = 1/DG$ , hence $DG=1/\sin (y)$
In the right-angle triangle with $x$ , we have $\sin (x) = AH/DG$ , hence $AH=\sin (x) / \sin (y)$
The same way using the right-angle triangle with $45-y$ , we have $\sin (45-y) = 1/DF$ , hence $DF=1/\sin (45-y)$
With the right-angle triangle with $45-x$ , we have $\sin (45-x) = AH/DF$ , hence $AH=\sin (45-x) / \sin (45-y)$
We then get $\sin (x) / \sin (y)=\sin (45-x) / \sin (45-y)$
Equivalently , $\sin (45-y) / \sin (y)=\sin (45-x) / \sin (x)$
Expanding , $[ \sin (45) \cos (y) - \cos (45) \sin (y) ] / \sin (y) = [ \sin (45) \cos (x) - \cos (45) \sin (x) ] / \sin (x)$
Evaluating that , $[ \sin (45) \cot (y) - \cos (45) ] = [ \sin (45) \cot (x) - \cos (45) ]$
$\cot (y) = \cot (x)$
$y = x$ ( within the relevant Domain )
We thus have Congruent triangles , hence $DH=DA$

Thanks! I understood the intuition, but would you please complete the solution?
